# Unload information when clicked in button with DOM - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

my question is based in previous question [generate HTML page using DOM - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105221/generate-html-page-using-dom-javascript) and based in this ìmage`in down, I could solve the question with @MasterDJon orientation` it´s work very well, but it´s not complete,

because still missing the create the event for `student informaion button` and like the scripts and page it´s work, but I need to ***Unload_Student*** to see information when the same is **select in checkbox**  and I need to **return to the homepage or school page**  when I click in ***button return to the school page***, If you don´t understand my question, try to **run code snippet** to see the result.

**ps:** summarizing and concluding , I want to just move on to student page and then return to home page with `button event`

[image]

```js
var school = new School(1);

function Student(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.div = null;

  var self = this;
  Unload_Student(this.id);

  function Unload_Student(index) {

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "student";

    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.style.color = "red";

    var title = document.createTextNode("Student " + index + " informations:");
    h1.appendChild(title);

    var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.style.color = "blue";

    var subtitle = document.createTextNode("List Of Books:");
    h3.appendChild(subtitle);

    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(h3);


    var btnBack = document.createElement("button");
    var btnBackText = document.createTextNode("Return to School Page");
    btnBack.appendChild(btnBackText);
    btnBack.onclick = function() {
      //return to school page
      //but it´s not function
      school.Unload_School();
    }

    div.appendChild(btnBack);

    document.body.appendChild(div);
  };

}


function School(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.index = 0;
  this.students = {};
  this.studentsList = document.createElement('DIV');

  var self = this;
  Unload_School();

  function Unload_School() {

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "school";

    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.style.color = "red";

    var title = document.createTextNode("High School");
    h1.appendChild(title);

    var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.style.color = "blue";

    var subtitle = document.createTextNode("List Of Students:");
    h3.appendChild(subtitle);

    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(h3);

    div.appendChild(self.studentsList);


    var btnCreate = document.createElement("button");
    var btnCreateText = document.createTextNode("Create");
    btnCreate.appendChild(btnCreateText);
    btnCreate.onclick = function() {
      school.createStudent();

    }

    var btnRemove = document.createElement("button");
    var btnRemoveText = document.createTextNode("Remove");
    btnRemove.appendChild(btnRemoveText);
    btnRemove.onclick = function() {
      school.removeStudents();
    }


    var btnInf = document.createElement("button");
    var btnInfText = document.createTextNode("Student Information");
    btnInf.appendChild(btnInfText);
    btnInf.onclick = function() {
      school.studentInformations();
    }

    div.appendChild(btnCreate);
    div.appendChild(btnRemove);
    div.appendChild(btnInf);

    document.body.appendChild(div);
  };

}

School.prototype.createStudent = function() {
  this.students[this.index] = new Student(this.index);
  this.showStudent(this.index);
  this.index++;
};

School.prototype.showStudent = function(id) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div["data-id"] = this.students[id].id;

  var chkbox = document.createElement("input");
  chkbox.type = "checkbox";
  chkbox.name = "Student" + this.students[id].id;
  chkbox.id = chkbox.name;
  div.appendChild(chkbox);

  var chkText = document.createTextNode("Student " + this.students[id].id);
  div.appendChild(chkText);

  this.students[id].div = div;
  this.studentsList.appendChild(div);
};

School.prototype.removeStudents = function(id) {
  //this call the function to remove the students
  var totalRemoved = 0;
  for (var studentElementIndex in this.studentsList.childNodes) {
    var studentElement = this.studentsList.childNodes[studentElementIndex - totalRemoved];
    if (studentElement.childNodes[0].checked) {
      this.removeStudent(studentElement['data-id']);
      totalRemoved++;
    }
  }
};

School.prototype.removeStudent = function(id) {
  //this call the function to remove the students
  if (!this.students[id]) return;

  if (this.students[id].div != null)
    this.studentsList.removeChild(this.students[id].div);

  delete this.students[id];
};


School.prototype.studentInformations = function() {
  for (var studentIndex in this.studentsList.childNodes) {
    var studentInf = this.studentsList.childNodes[studentIndex];
    if (studentInf.childNodes[0].checked) {
      this.studentInformation(studentInf['piso-id']);
    }
  }
};


School.prototype.studentInformation = function(id) {
  if (!this.students[id]) {
    return;
  }
  if (this.students[id].div != null) {
    //need to call the UnloadStudent
    this.students[id].Unload_Student(this.students[id].id);

  }
};
```

```css
#school {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
#student {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

[id] h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

[id] h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

[id] button {
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>High School</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="school"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to do this is pure JavaScript?  Can you use a framework?

Comment: @whipdancer, it´s just in javascripts and DOM, no framework, I wanna call `function Unload_Student(index)` when I select the student in checkbox, and if I select the student in checkbox I can remove but I wanna select and see information with call o `function Unload_Student(index)`

Comment: @whipdancer,  I put this `function UnloadStdent(index)`  inside  `student class` to see the result, but I need to call when I click `student information button` and if is possible to return to homepage with `button return to school page`

Comment: The function Unload_Student is private and can not be called outside a Student object.

Comment: Ok, @MasterDJon I understand. maybe if I create a prototype of function outside Student object like Student.prototype.Unload_Student ?

Comment: Yes! Read the last comment of your previous question and search those on internet.

Comment: @MasterDJon, I have found the solution and it´s work, I create the new the public variable that return the Unload_Student `this.showInf = function(){ return Unload_Students(this.id);}` and in button student information event `button.onclick=function(){this.students[id].showInf();}` I will update my question and now I wanna go back to the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem is that I called the `private function` outside class and the solution is create the `public function`that call the `private function`, merit for @MasterDJon for your orientation, thanks

```js
var school = new School(1);

function Student(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.div = null;

  //public function to call private function
  this.showInformation = function() {
    Unload_Student(this.id);
  }

  //private function
  function Unload_Student(index) {

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "student";

    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.style.color = "red";

    var title = document.createTextNode("Student " + index + " informations:");
    h1.appendChild(title);

    var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.style.color = "blue";

    var subtitle = document.createTextNode("List Of Books:");
    h3.appendChild(subtitle);

    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(h3);


    var btnBack = document.createElement("button");
    var btnBackText = document.createTextNode("Return to School Page");
    btnBack.appendChild(btnBackText);
    btnBack.onclick = function() {
      //call school page to Unloadd_School
      //it´s work
      school.schoolPage();
    }

    div.appendChild(btnBack);

    document.body.appendChild(div);
  };

}


function School(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.index = 0;
  this.students = {};
  this.studentsList = document.createElement('DIV');
  var self = this;
  Unload_School();

  //public function to call private function
  this.schoolPage = function() {
    Unload_School();
  }

  //private function
  function Unload_School() {

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "school";

    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.style.color = "red";

    var title = document.createTextNode("High School");
    h1.appendChild(title);

    var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.style.color = "blue";

    var subtitle = document.createTextNode("List Of Students:");
    h3.appendChild(subtitle);

    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(h3);

    div.appendChild(self.studentsList);


    var btnCreate = document.createElement("button");
    var btnCreateText = document.createTextNode("Create");
    btnCreate.appendChild(btnCreateText);
    btnCreate.onclick = function() {
      school.createStudent();

    }

    var btnRemove = document.createElement("button");
    var btnRemoveText = document.createTextNode("Remove");
    btnRemove.appendChild(btnRemoveText);
    btnRemove.onclick = function() {
      school.removeStudents();
    }


    var btnInf = document.createElement("button");
    var btnInfText = document.createTextNode("Student Information");
    btnInf.appendChild(btnInfText);
    btnInf.onclick = function() {
      school.studentInformations();
    }

    div.appendChild(btnCreate);
    div.appendChild(btnRemove);
    div.appendChild(btnInf);

    document.body.appendChild(div);
  };

}

School.prototype.createStudent = function() {
  this.students[this.index] = new Student(this.index);
  this.showStudent(this.index);
  this.index++;
};

School.prototype.showStudent = function(id) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div["data-id"] = this.students[id].id;

  var chkbox = document.createElement("input");
  chkbox.type = "checkbox";
  chkbox.name = "Student" + this.students[id].id;
  chkbox.id = chkbox.name;
  div.appendChild(chkbox);

  var chkText = document.createTextNode("Student " + this.students[id].id);
  div.appendChild(chkText);

  this.students[id].div = div;
  this.studentsList.appendChild(div);
};

School.prototype.removeStudents = function(id) {
  //this call the function to remove the students
  var totalRemoved = 0;
  for (var studentElementIndex in this.studentsList.childNodes) {
    var studentElement = this.studentsList.childNodes[studentElementIndex - totalRemoved];
    if (studentElement.childNodes[0].checked) {
      this.removeStudent(studentElement['data-id']);
      totalRemoved++;
    }
  }
};

School.prototype.removeStudent = function(id) {
  //this call the function to remove the students
  if (!this.students[id]) return;

  if (this.students[id].div != null)
    this.studentsList.removeChild(this.students[id].div);

  delete this.students[id];
};


School.prototype.studentInformations = function() {
  for (var studentIndex in this.studentsList.childNodes) {
    var studentInf = this.studentsList.childNodes[studentIndex];
    if (studentInf.childNodes[0].checked) {
      this.studentInformation(studentInf['data-id']);
    }
  }
};


School.prototype.studentInformation = function(id) {
  if (!this.students[id]) {
    return;
  }
  if (this.students[id].div != null) {
    // call the showInformation to Unload_Students
    //it´s work
    this.students[id].showInformation();

  }
};
```

```css
#school {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

#student {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

[id] h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

[id] h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

[id] button {
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>High School</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="school"></div>
</body>

</html>
```